# Are model airplanes on topic here?

Tags: discussion, questions

Just curious, are model airplane questions on topic here? I don't know what else to put here so that the question is long enough to get past the bot.

Comment: there have been questions about where they can fly and such,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are remote controlled aircraft on-topic?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/are-remote-controlled-aircraft-on-topic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be more specific about what you mean by "model airplane questions." If you mean questions about how RC aircraft interact with the airspace system, or how they are regulated, then those have been considered on-topic here.

If you are referring to questions about the manufacturing, construction, or operation of model or RC airplanes, then those are generally considered off-topic because we are primarily a pilot-oriented community, and most pilots simply aren't very knowledgeable or interested in those sorts of questions. You wouldn't be very likely to get good answers from us anyway.

Comment: This answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The site is about Aviation, and I think that model airplanes fit quite nicely here.

Questions about aerodynamics are virtually identical to larger scale aircraft, as well as regulatory type questions about where they can be flown.

I know a lot of pilots (as well as non-pilots) that fly model airplanes, and it would be great if the model aircraft community joined us here since there is a fair amount of overlap.  The portion that is more specific can easily be handled with our tag system (in a way similar to Stack Overflow keeping different languages separate via tags).

I would suggest asking and seeing how it goes.