# Drones.SE is in the Commitment phase

Tags: discussion

**Edit**: Unfortunately, this proposal didn't pass the commitment phase.

---

Due to there likely being some overlap of interests among some of our users here, I just wanted to post here that the [Drones.SE proposal on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107036/drones?referrer=klelgTtuLBGlMLc6hgPLhA2) has completed the Discussion phase and is now in the Commitment phase. It needs about 120 more users to commit to using it before it will enter the private beta.

---

Regarding the differences between Aviation.SE and the proposed Drones.SE, there's some discussion of what would be a different about them in the Area 51 question [How is this different from Av.Se and Ro.Se?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26999/125096)

The on-topicness of drone-related questions here on Aviation.SE has been discussed a couple of times in the past in Meta:

- [Are questions about hobby-grade drones on-topic in general?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/755)
- [Are remote controlled aircraft on-topic?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/755)

If you have some input on distinction between the two sites, feel free to post new answers on the Area 51 question and/or one of the Meta questions here on Aviation.

There may well end up being some overlap along the border between the two sites, but that's fine and not particularly unusual for SE sites. If a particular question is on-topic for both sites, the asker can pick which one they want to ask on. If/when the Drones proposal goes into public beta, then we may want to have another meta discussion here on Aviation Meta regarding drone-related questions and how to handle migrations and so forth. The results of that would likely end up depending at least somewhat on how the private beta of Drones goes and the direction that site takes for itself.

Comment: Can you add more information here?

Comment: So, where do other UAS system questions belong then? Here or drones?

Comment: @NoahWood I edited to include links to Meta discussions here and a question on Area 51 about the differences between the sites. My personal opinion is that a lot of it will probably end up coming down to scale. For questions about something on the size and complexity scale of an MQ-1 Predator, I suspect you're going to find more expert information here on Aviation. On the other hand, for something on the scale of a DJI Phantom, I suspect you'll find better information on Drones, regardless of the use case of the particular UAS system.